# mySQL search in multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have a Table:

```
| USERNAME | FORNAME | SURNAME | TELNUMBER | ZIPCODE ....
```

and I want to search username forename and surname in 1 query / statement .. and I don't want multiple lines ..
like.. lets say ..

username : maria33
forname  : maria

so this should be 1 row .. when I search mar%

and not 2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a prepared statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  username LIKE ?
    OR forname  LIKE ?
    OR surname  LIKE ?
```

Then if you fill in all three parameters with the same string, `"%mar%"`:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "mar%");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mar%");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "mar%");
```

You'd end up with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  username LIKE "mar%"
    OR forname  LIKE "mar%"
    OR surname  LIKE "mar%"
```

Comment: Thank .. and as a prepared statement ?